# Checkbox wont uncheck

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

here is my code.

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
            Organizational Units
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in Model.OUList)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedOUs" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />
                @Html.Label(item.Text, new { @class = "control-label" })
                <br />
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this code doesn't allow me to untick if i have selected an org unit. what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't believe checked is a true/false value, rather the mere existence of the checked attribute means that the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Use `<input type="checkbox"  @(item.Selected ? "checked" :"")/>`, Add attribute only if `item.Selected`

Answer (score 1):

The check state of the checkbox is controlled by the existence of the `checked` attribute, rather than the value inside.

`checked="true"`, `checked="asd"` and `checked="false"` will all render the checkbox checked, so rather than binding directly to the `Selected` value, add the checkbox attribute only when `Selected == true`.